# Finding top 2 maximum value betweens alpha numeric in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Need to find top 2 maximum values between alphanumeric numbers. Data looks like below
"2FB","4CB","0FW","4CW"

Here output will be like: 4CB,4CW.

The alphabets will always the same.. only numbers will change. The above data is an outpur from a function which I am storing it in 4 string variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

earlier I've saved the output in each excel rows, and with below vba code used to retrieve max value.. but its not working as expected as I need the first 2 values now

```
Evaluate("IF(MAX(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "))>2,INDEX(" & rng.Address & ",MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & ")),COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "),0)),0)")
```

Comment: earlier I've saved the output in each excel rows, and with below vba code used to retrieve max value.. but its not working as expected as I need the first 2 values now  Evaluate("IF(MAX(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "))>2,INDEX(" & rng.Address & ",MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & ")),COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "),0)),0)")

Comment: in rng I stored the values of 2,4,0,4. Also it sometimes getting 0 as output.. as I am new to vba need to check for any other alternatives

Comment: What do you mean by "Maximum" value? What role does alphabet play into the "Maximum" part? Do you mean "4A" > "4B" (Alphabetical order in consideration?) or are they to be considered same (Just checking the numeric part)?

Comment: yes only numeric part

Comment: `yes only numeric part – bvsnkiran 1 hour ago`: Then your question needs a very different type of approach. If your list has `2FB,4CB,0FW,4CW,4AB` then which 2 do you want from `4CB,4CW,4AB` and what is the logic that should be followed in deciding those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an ArrayList object:

```
Sub Test()

'Initialize your input:
Dim arr(): arr = Array("2FB", "4CB", "0FW", "4CW")

'Create the arraylist object:
With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    'Loop over your array to load arraylist:
    For Each el In arr
        .Add el
    Next
    
    'Sort our array ascending and reverse the outcome:
    .Sort
    .Reverse
    
    'Demo lines, we allready got our two largest values:
    Debug.Print .Item(0)
    Debug.Print .Item(1)
    
    'Slice away redundant items and report back in array:
    .RemoveRange 2, .Count - 2
    arr = .ToArray
      
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: the values are dynamic and can the result will be returned

Comment: thanks a lot :) let me try and will get back to you JvdV

Comment: HI @JvdV, your function is working.. but thing is as it is getting called by multiple times (like 100 times per 2min) The overall performance is getting degraded.. could you suggest any changes in the code..

Comment: @bvsnkiran. Best is to open a new question with your problem, a good description and your attempt to solve it.